# How to add Multiple CSS classes Using Bindngs

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a data binding, In which I have to apply two css classes

```
data-bind ="css: isHiddenStage"
```

**isHiddenStage** ==> function returning a css class based on some Logic,
This is working fine, and I want to apply another css classes based on some condition

```
css:{ my-class:$index() + 1 === 10 }
```

Note: Here i can't use **isHiddenStage** function to check the condition
So finally I got this:

```
    data-bind ="css: isHiddenStage, css:{ my-class:$index() + 1 === 10 }"
```

Which Is not working may be because, I can't use **css** twice in a binding. 
Is there any alternative.

Regards

Comment: Consider renaming `isHiddenStage` to `getHiddenStageCssClass`. Or if you can't rename that function for some reason, wrap it. `isHiddenStage` sounds like a boolean property.

Answer (score 3):

There cannot be multiple css bindings on the same element. Create a function that returns all css classes separated by spaces to be used in a single css binding.

HTML

```
<div data-bind="css: getCssClassesForIndex($index)"></div>
```

View Model

```
this.getCssClassesForIndex = function (index) {
    var cssClasses = this.isHiddenStage() || '';
    if ((index + 1) === 10) {
        cssClasses += ' my-class';
    }
    return cssClasses;
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: Nice.  The thought of passing in `$index` didn't occur to me

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
data-bind ="css:{ isHiddenStage: true, 'my-class': $index() + 1 === 10 }"
```

This way the isHiddenStage() class will always be applied since its condition is always true.

Note that I put 'my-class' in quotes because it was not a valid identifier.

[Knockout documentation link source](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question the way I understand it.  `isHiddenStage` isn't the class to be applied (if it was, you could stick it in a normal `class` attribute), rather it's a function that can return a different class based on the logic within it.

Comment: In that case, cant you just add an extra param to isHiddenStage() that would allow you to output 'my-class' in addition to its normal return values or combine the two into a new ko.computed() called calculateClass() or something? If your functions were posted I could give a better answer.

Comment: @br4d I thought, But I'm not allowed to change the existing function :(